# Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application' how can I solved this Problem?

Tags: android

I'm Beginner, this is a old project, i want to start this project. but this is my problem. how can I solve this problem?

**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ip62.png)**

I'm Beginner, this is a old project, i want to start this project. but this is my problem. how can I solve this problem?